# Correct cleaning up after accessing Oracle DB from .Net code

Tags: .net, oracle

Is this the proper way to clean up after myself when using a connection to an oracle-server, using system.data.oracleclient?

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;

var con = new OracleConnection("some connection string");
con.Open();
con.Close();
con = null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OracleConnection` implements `IDisposable` so a good idea is to employ the `using` construct. I.e.

```
using(var connection = new OracleConnection("connection string")) {
   // do stuff
}
```

This will make sure the connection is closed and disposed even in the case of an error. I don't see any reason to null the reference. It will go out of scope and will be cleaned so no need to clutter the code with that IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.
You might also want to call `con.Dispose()` after `Close`. This makes sure the connection is released immediately without waiting for the .NET garbage collector.

Remember to also Close any readers you use after reading data.

Comment: Actually, Dispose() calls Close() for you (from looking at it in reflector). So you only need to call Dispose(), or wrap the OracleConnection in a using {...} block